# How to know if you have Docker Version, 1.13?

Tags: docker, version

How do you know if you have Docker Version 1.13 or higher? My Client/Server version is : 1.6.2 and Client/Server API version is: 1.18. This makes me think I have a version above 1.13; however, I don't have the functionality of Docker 1.13. i.e. I can't use "docker stack deploy" or "docker container".

Comment: you can run `docker version` and get the details

Answer (score 0):

You can in terminal run command `docker --version`